# Kubernetes automatically adds the storageClassName to PVC

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-storage, kubernetes-pvc

I have a helm chart that contains PV and PVC to mount NFS volumes and this works fine. I need to install this helm chart on a new cluster that has very strict and limited security measures and I also see that my pods are pending because they can't mount the NFS.

After some investigations, I found out that the problem is the PVC and PV have different storageClassName:

```sh
kubectl -n 57 describe pvc gstreamer-claim


Events:
  Type       Reason             Age                 From                         Message
  ----       ------             ----                ----                         -------
  Warning    VolumeMismatch     98s (x83 over 21m)  persistentvolume-controller  Cannot bind to requested volume "gstreamer-57": storageClassName does not match
```

This is very strange since the PVC in my helm chart doesn't have any storageClassName at all:
PVC:

```yaml
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: gstreamer-claim
    namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  spec:
    volumeName: gstreamer-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 10Gi
```

PV:

```yaml
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolume
  metadata:
    name: gstreamer-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
  spec:
    capacity:
      storage: 10Gi
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
    mountOptions:
      - hard
      - nfsvers=4.1
    nfs:
      server: {{ .Values.global.nfsserver }}
      path: /var/nfs/general/gstreamer-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

I tried to edit the PVC but I was not able to change it.

Why this is happening? Can it be related to the cluster security?
How to fix this?

### Update

Storage class info:

```sh
kubectl -n 57 get sc
NAME                      PROVISIONER                                       AGE
local-storage (default)   kubernetes.io/no-provisioner                      54d
nfs-client                cluster.local/nfs-client-nfs-client-provisioner   43m


kubectl -n 57 get sc local-storage -o yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"},"name":"local-storage"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/no-provisioner","volumeBindingMode":"WaitForFirstConsumer"}
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-31T20:46:39Z"
  name: local-storage
  resourceVersion: "458"
  selfLink: /apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/local-storage
  uid: b8352eb1-7390-11ea-84a7-fa163e393634
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Comment: share output of kubectl get sc

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added the info and I see that the default sc is `local-storage`. Is it enough if I just remove the `storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"` or I need to do more stuff?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I want to see you answering this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Dynamic provisioning you don't need to create a PV explicitly. Create a PVC with storage class `nfs-client`.

```
apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: gstreamer-claim
    namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  spec:
    volumeName: gstreamer-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 10Gi
    storageClassName: nfs-client
```

Another option would be to make `nfs-client` as the default storage class and there will be no need to specify `storageClassName: nfs-client` in PVC.